# Select2.js not working in dropdown

Tags: knockout.js, durandal, jquery-select2

I Am using Select2.js ,KnockoutJs,Durandal 2.0

```
var ViewModel =
    [
        { id: "AL", text: "Alabama" },
        { id: "AK", text: "Alaska" },
        { id: "AZ", text: "Arizona" },
        { id: "AR", text: "Arkansas" },
        { id: "CA", text: "California" },
        { id: "CO", text: "Colorado" }
    ]
var stateQuery = function (query) {

    var states = [];
    ko.utils.arrayForEach(states, function (state) {
        if (state.text.search(new RegExp(query.term, 'i')) >= 0) {
            states.push(state);
    }
    });
```

While Binding in drop down it is working fine.But if i change **text** to **Text_Name** i am getting *can not convert to **upperCase** of undefined.*

```
var ViewModel =
    [
        { id: "AL", Text_Name: "Alabama" },
        { id: "AK", Text_Name: "Alaska" },
        { id: "AZ", Text_Name: "Arizona" },
        { id: "AR", Text_Name: "Arkansas" },
        { id: "CA", Text_Name: "California" },
        { id: "CO", Text_Name: "Colorado" }
    ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a select2 convention. [See the documentation](http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/):

> The default implementation expects the object to have a text property
>   that is returned.

To change this behaviour you should specify the functions `formatResult` and `formatSelection` and specify the new text property:

```
function format(item) {
    return item.Text_Name
}
```

If you are using a Knockout binding handler:

```
<select data-bind="options: states, optionsValue: 'id', optionsText: 'text', value: states, select2: { formatSelection: format, formatResult: format  }"></select>
```

Comment: Hi thx Margabit its worging fine.But search function is nt wrkng. My html is like this<input type="hidden" data-bind="value: ViewModel,optionsText: 'text', select2: { minimumInputLength: 1, query: stateQuery,formatSelection: format, formatResult: format  }" style="width: 300px">

Comment: Please, post another question with this new problem so we can write a proper answer ;)